# How to disable GitLab Sidekiq Broadcasting Unwanted Data to Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, sidekiq, broadcast

I’m encountering an issue with GitLab Sidekiq that appears to be sending data to Google Cloud (35.190.167.255) on every pageload, even though I have not configured it to do so. Despite my efforts to disable this behavior, I’ve been unsuccessful in resolving the problem. I am running the latest omnibus version.

Could someone please explain why this is happening and how to disable unwanted behaviour? Any insights and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

1. Setting metrics_enabled to false in the configuration:

```
sidekiq['metrics_enabled'] = false
```

2. Adjusting logging levels in various GitLab components:

```
gitaly['configuration'] = {
  logging_level: 'ERROR',
}
gitlab_rails['env'] = {
  "GITLAB_LOG_LEVEL" => "ERROR"
}
registry['log_level'] = 'error'
gitlab_shell['log_level'] = 'ERROR'
```

Despite these configurations, the issue persists, and GitLab Sidekiq continues to transmit data to Google Cloud on every pageload and job entry.